What does the verb advantage mean in this sentence from chapter one of "Wuthering Heights"?
In the first chapter of Wuthering Heights Emily Brontë writes:

The apartment and furniture would have been nothing extraordinary as belonging to a homely, northern farmer, with a stubborn countenance, and stalwart limbs set out to advantage in knee-breeches and gaiters. Such an individual seated in his arm-chair, his mug of ale frothing on the round table before him, is to be seen in any circuit of five or six miles among these hills, if you go at the right time after dinner.

I looked up the verb in two dictionaries, yet methinks it does not mean 'to benefit somebody' or 'to provide with an advantage' in this context.
What does advantage mean in this context?
